# Template variable or template typedef in a scope

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Why template variable or template typedef cannot be declared inside of a scope?

I would like to write a code in c++17 like this

```
auto foo = [](auto fun, auto... x) {
  template <typename T>
  using ReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<fun, T>;

  if constexpr (!(std::is_same_v<void, ReturnType<decltype(x)>> || ... ||
                  false)) {
    return std::tuple<ReturnType<decltype(x)>...>(fun(x)...);
  } else {
    (fun(x), ...);
    return;
  }
};
```

This code defines a function `foo` which takes a function `fun` and bunch of arguments `x...`. If all of the return types `fun(x)` are not `void` then return a tuple of results. If atleast one of the return types is `void` then just call all the functions but return `void`.

In this simple example, I can of course replace `ReturnType<decltype(x)>` with `decltype(fun(x))`, but in my use case the actual type is much more complicated and the above code serves only as a motivation.

Also, I hate writing `ReturnType<decltype(x)>`. I would much prefer writing `ReturnType(x)`, but that is probably not possible.

---

*Solution I do not like:* Define template typedef outside of the function as

```
template<typename Fun, typename T>
using ReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<Fun,T>;
```

and then in the function use

```
ReturnType<decltype(fun),delctype(x)>
```

Which is getting long and I have to put every local type as a template parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is actually simpler without introducing any helpers:

```
if constexpr ((!std::is_void_v<decltype(fun(x))> && ...)) {
    return std::tuple(fun(x)...);
} else {
    (fun(x), ...);
}
```

`&&` and `||` have default values for empty packs (`true` and `false`, respectively), so you don't have to turn them into unary operators. And you don't need `invoke_result_t` since you're just directly calling. And even if you did:

```
using F = decltype(fun);
if constexpr ((!std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<F, decltype(x))> && ...)) {
    return std::tuple(std::invoke(fun, x)...);
} else {
    (fun(x), ...);
}
```

Not much longer.

---

That said, I find this construct not very helpful - given that you get wildly different results for the `void` and non-`void` cases. Maybe `f(x)` is still an `X` but `f(y)` is `void`, we'd get `foo(x,x)` being `tuple<X,X>` but `foo(x,y)` being `void`? Hard to code around.

I would suggest instead of dropping all the return types, just work around the broken ones. As in:

```
struct Void { };

template <typename F, typename... Args,
    typename R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>,
    REQUIRES(std::is_void_v<R>)>
Void invoke_void(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return Void{};
}

template <typename F, typename... Args,
    typename R = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>,
    REQUIRES(!std::is_void_v<R>)>
R invoke_void(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

And now, we can always just call the function and return it:

```
auto foo = [](auto fun, auto... x) {
    return std::tuple(invoke_void(fun, x)...);
};
```